# BigQuery table data export using API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I wanted to export BigQuery table data using API and would like to know that is there any charges for API?

Answer (score 2):

Export is free as operation. But you will be charged for storage you will use for files in Google Cloud Storage - you can download it quickly to your local machine - but I believe it would be still small charge for outboud operation. But it depends on how big data you export if it KB/MB - it is free - if it is TB/PB you may inquire big bill.

There is info about GCS pricing https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing